# multiply Python Quad integration by float

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

Hello I'm quite new to python and I'm trying to work through a set of equations. I'm trying to multiple the result of the quad integration by a float my code is:

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy.special as sp
from scipy import integrate
import math

Tb = 7.2
Tc = 9.3
t = Tb / Tc
n = 2*10**-6
L = 50*10**-6
W = 80*10**-9
a = 3*10**-2
s1 = W/ (2*n)
y1 = (L+(W/2)) / (2*n)
x0 = 0.015
r0 = 4*x0
s2 = (r0 / n)/1000000
print s2
y0 = (x0 / n)/1000000
def t1(t):
    return  t**-1*sp.kv(0, s2)
def t2(t):
    return t**-1*sp.iv(0, s2)
print t2
Fk2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2) 
FI2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t2, s1, s2)
print Fk2 , FI2
```

I keep getting the error

```
     25 print t2
---> 26 Fk2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2)
     27 FI2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t2, s1, s2)
     28 print Fk2 , FI2

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I'm quite unsure as to what todo, I've tried replacing `def t1(t)` by lambda function but again that has done nothing. Any help is really appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: See the `Returns` section of http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, I'll start by saying that whenever you have an error that you don't understand, split the line up into multiple separate steps so you can figure out exactly what the error refers to, like this:

```
temp = integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2)
print "temp:", temp
Fk2 = (math.pi**-2) * temp
```

Then you can see that the error is that temp is a tuple, and there's no definition for how to multiply a tuple by a float.

```
Fk2 = (math.pi**-2) * np.array(temp[:2])
```

And you can see in [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html) what each term refers to.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was working for a bit until now it has started throughinh this error at me `IntegrationWarning: The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  warnings.warn(msg, IntegrationWarning)
`

Comment: It will work best to ask this as a separate question so you can define the circumstances, etc.  Also, note that if you call `quad` with `full_output=True`, one of the return values will be a dictionary that contains additional information, including info on the errors.  Expect, though, that these things will usually be harder to track down than the simple syntax error of your original problem, and possibly require understanding of the algorithm, etc.

Answer (score 1):

integrate.quad returns a tuple of length 2 by default, the first entry is the answer and the second is an estimate of the error of the answer. To use the result in a further calculation, try

```
Fk2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2)[0]
FI2 = (math.pi**-2) * integrate.quad(t2, s1, s2)[0]
```

This selects the answer only and multiplies it by the float.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Fk2 = [(math.pi**-2) * e for e in integrate.quad(t1, s1, s2)]
FI2 = [(math.pi**-2) * e for e in integrate.quad(t2, s1, s2)]
```